# Dividing Long with Double in Java producing wrong results

Tags: java, long-integer

I am trying to divide a `Long` in Java with a percentage like `0.99` and it keeps giving me crazy results.

```
long totalBytes = 5877062
long final = (long) (totalBytes / 0.99) // IT PRODUCES 5936426 > totalBytes
```

[image]

what am i doing wrong ? For `1.00` it works well , if i give `0.95 ++` it always produces something bigger than the `totalBytes`.

Why am i loosing precision ?

`Java Version 10.0.2`

Comment: Um...dividing a whole number by some value _less_ than 1 results in a number _larger_ than the original dividend.  This is just basic math.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So Tim how i can get the percentage of number i want from the totalBytes ?

Comment: try multiplying.

Comment: that is not a Java question, pure maths (shouldn't be hard to test this on a calculator, smart phone or whatever)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Good , but now StackOverFlow doesn't allow me to delete :( and i am getting -5

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I voted it for closing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take a certain percentage of the total bytes, you should be *multiplying* the percentage decimal against the total bytes value:

```
long totalBytes = 5877062;
long percent = (long) (0.99 * totalBytes);
```

Comment: I feel ashamed ... should i delete or keep the question :) ?

Comment: Your call.  Is there some reason why you thought to use your current equation?

Comment: No i was just trying to do what you answer here , but i didn't knew . Always i forget the stuff with percentages lol . Thank you so much .